# How to retrieve multiple maximum values from each keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, networkx, junit-jupiter

How do I retrieve multiple maximum values (or top N values) from each keys in my dictionary.

```
communities_dict = {1: "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","CB" 
                    2: "H","I","J","K","L","M","N","XY" 
                    3: "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","GT"
                    4: "V","W","X","Y","Z","AB" "HH","FF", 
                    5: "CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL","HG","FR","RR"}
# load the network graph 

G = nx.read_adjlist("./data/networkgraph.csv", delimiter = ',')

# cluster the network graph

partition = community.best_partition(G)

# Get a set of the communities

communities = set(partition.values())
    
# Create a dictionary mapping community number to nodes within that community

communities_dict = {c: [k for k, v in partition.items() if v == c] for c in communities}
    
# Filter that dictionary to map community to the node of highest degree within the community

highest_degree = {k: max(v, key=lambda x: G.degree(x)) for k, v in communities_dict.items()}
```

This is the dictionary I get back from highest_degree is:

```
1: "A"
2: "I"
3: "Q"
4: "AB" 
5: "CD"
```

But I would ideally want the top 3 nodes with the highest degree for each key instead the just one.

```
1: "A","B","C"
2: "I", "J","K"
3: "Q","P","Q"
4: "V","W","X"
5: "CD", "EF","GH"
```

Comment: hint: `key=lambda x: G.degree(x)` => `key=G.degree`. I suggest that you remove the `....` to create a real [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `3` nodes with highest degree you can use `sorted` and then slice your new list with `[-3:]` to get the last 3 elements. In your example this would look like:

```
highest_degree = {k: sorted(v, key=G.degree)[-3:] for k, v in communities_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Np :) @Jeff could you click the check mark beside my answer and vote-up the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple values of each key you must use [] for your values. Your code has some syntax errors like You have not used a comma to separate the previous values from the next key.
your code must be like that:

'''

```
    dict = {1: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","CB"],
            2: ["H","I","J","K","L","M","N","XY"],
            3: ["O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","GT"],
            4: ["V","W","X","Y","Z","AB" "HH","FF"], 
            5: ["CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL","HG","FR","RR"]}
```

'''

Comment: While you are technically correct, I would assume that the OP just sloppily reduced his actual code for the question. Even though you provided correct syntax for the dictionary, you are not actually answering his question in any way.